# Como inserir a biblioteca DroidSoapClient em minha aplicação Android?

Tags: android, soap

Estou com dificuldades para importar a biblioteca DroidSoapClient em minha aplicação, utilizo o Android Studio para desenvolver e estou inserindo esta biblioteca na pasta Main, mas parece que a importação não está lozalicando o arquivo, ou muito provavelmente estou errando em algum ponto.

O que devo fazer para importar corretamente esta biblioteca? https://code.google.com/p/droidsoapclient/

Comment: Poderia postar seu `gradle.build`?

Comment: Em relação ao local, não pode colocar `jar` na pasta `src`, é na pasta `libs`. E apague todos os `compile file`, a `compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')` já vai pegar o `jar` do `droidsoapclient` e adicionar no apk.

Comment: Adicionei o droidsoapclient na pasta libs, adicionei à blibioteca e corrigi o gradle.build para 
`dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
}`,

Agora como devo fazer o comando o import?

Comment: Basta seguir o tutorial do site, usando o `SoapClient`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve inserir o .jar na pasta libs.

Em seguida, clique com o botão direito sobre ele e escolha uma opção que está mais no final:

**Add as Libray**

Pronto!

Verifique isso no arquivo build.gradle do app (o procedimento acima já deve funcionar)

```
dependencies {
    // ================== LIBRARIES ======================
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'], dir: 'libs')
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Comment: Adicionei a biblioteca da maneira informada, mas ainda estou errado no caminho da importação.

Comment: Que erro está aparecendo para você?